# Insert (using safe:true) not inserting anything to MongoDB in nodeJS, despite saying it does

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a relatively extensive webapp that is all built in NodeJS and MongoDB using the mongodb-node-driver. Right now I've come across the most bizarre of issues.

I have this function:

```
function newLoc(req, res){
    var newloc = req.body;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newloc));
    locs.insert(newloc,{safe:true},function(err,doc){
        if(err) returnError(res,'aww shit locinsertion error!\n\n'+err.message);
        else{
            console.log(doc[0]);
            returnSuccess(res,"The ID of the location you just added is: "+doc[0]['_id']);
        }
    });
}
```

Everything is set up properly (in terms of connection opening) and returnSuccess works just fine. `req.body` contains the data coming from a form that is sent via POST. Both of the console.log print the same thing, except the second one has an "_id" added and all of the keys don't have quotations around them.

However, NOTHING makes it to the database. No errors, the document is returned as if it was inserted, yet nothing is added. This is especially bizarre because this is not a problem ANYWHERE else in my code (and i do lots of inserts).

To add to the confusion, if I change `newloc` in the insert to be `{foo:bar}`, it does insert. Does anybody have any idea as to what might be going on?

**Edit** in response to christkv's request, here are the objects printed:

```
{"music":"art","array":[],"name":"sdf","info":"","date":"asdf","_id":"fSURBOvCU"}

{ muic: 'art',
  array: [],
  name: 'sdf',
  info: '',
  date: 'asdf',
  _id: 'fSURBOvCU' }
```

and nothing is being printed in the "mongod" process output, which i assume is where any errors would be logged as well.

also, when `console.log(JSON.stringify(newloc))` has the JSON.stringify removed, the outputs are identical.

Comment: What output is printed for your code sample .. is there an error message or success?  Also, what do the contents of "newloc" look like for an example that doesn't work?

Comment: Actually think you may want `var newloc = req.body.content;`

Comment: well that's the thing - it outputs a regular output. `doc` is supposed to return the item that is placed IN the database according to the spec. Therefore, if there is a doc returned, it should be in the database. The modules I'm using populate req.body, not req.body.contents, and the same exact thing works without issue in a different function (albeit a different collection, but that shouldn't affect anything when they're opened identically).

Comment: try doing a JSON stringify and then parse and insert the parsed object. I suspect there is something bad in your object. Also have a look at the mongodb log to see if it's protesting.

Comment: Can we have a look at the Objects printed by the console.log? Also, this might seem stupid, but are you sure that you are verifying in the correct db?

Comment: @ Amit - yeah, it's definitely the correct db (only one) and the correct collection. i've tried starting other collections too to make sure. @christkv - i'll try that right now - sounds promising. but why would it return a doc if something happened going in? @ both i'll post the outputs above in an edit so that you guys can see what's going on.

Comment: @christkv - yeah, you were right. having `var newloc = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));` makes it work fine. do you have any idea what the problem could be? also, if you wanna write out your answer down below as an official answer, i'd be happy to check it and upvote it.

Comment: hmm the only thing that's different about this particular function from the other one that uses req.body is that one of the body parts come from a `<textarea>` element, as opposed to being entirely `<input>` elements. could that be something to do with it?

Comment: @christkv aaaaaaaaaand i spoke too soon. it no longer works. it worked briefly, and then it stopped working. inserting the output using the mongo shell works just fine. is upserting the only other way to insert docs into a collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I've figured it out. My collection creation code originally looked like this:

```
  db.createCollection('place', function(err, pplace){
  if(err){
    console.log('db.createCollection error!');
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
        db.createCollection('tips', function(err, tipps){
            if(err){
                console.log('tips didnt get made: \n'+err);
            }
            else{
                                    place = pplace;
                tips = tipps;
                console.log(' place tips created');
            }
        }); 
 });
```

I don't create place or tips anywhere else since javascript automatically makes something a global if you don't give it a "var".

Now, I moved place = pplace to be right under the if statement after it's creation, and i also added a `var place, tips;` up above. This seems to have fixed the issue, and now everything I throw at my code seems to be inserted properly into my collection.

I'm still completely confused as to how this would change anything though, seeing as how I was getting the usual response for a SUCCESSFUL insert, not a failed one... Any thoughts?